# Extjs JsonStore baseParams are mixed up when calling load on Internet Explorer(any)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm using Extjs 3.4. When some details are loaded, I'm trying to set some params to a different store and load it; something like this:

```
countingTypeStore.setBaseParam(pdcId, parseInt(record.data.id));
countingTypeStore.setBaseParam(managementUnitId, managementUnitId);
countingTypeStore.load();
```

The remote method needs the parameters in this order and everything is fine with Firefox and Chrome but in IE the base params are mixed up (first is sent the second and viceversa). What should I do? Is there another way to dynamically set the store params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another way `countingTypeStore.load({params:{pdcId: calculatedId}})`;

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this before load:

```
countingTypeStore.baseParams = {
    pdcId : calculatedId,
    managementUnitId : mId
};
```

Comment: this will remove baseParams if already set by some other function and overwrite it with this value, which obviously is not a good thing

Comment: Yes, that is true. A better solution would be specifying these params directly in the load method.